# Get all columns in a row from Import-CSV with other delimiter

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I have a CSV with 100+ columns. Sometimes when I run the script, I want to select a few columns, but other times I need all columns. It will be written to a | pipe delimited file.

Is there a command/properties for Import-CSV that would allow to get a full row without specifying all the headers?

I tried the below code, but I have a hanging | pipe on the rows when I want all columns.

```
# powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File .\test.ps1 -NoExit -AllColumns
param(
    [switch]$AllColumns = $false
)
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter('output.txt')
Import-Csv 'test.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $writeLine = ""

    if($_.("Name") -eq "John") {
        if($AllColumns) {

            #$writeLine = All Columns with '|' delimiter     
            foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
                $writeLine = ($writeLine + $property.Value + '|')
                # Or this - $writeLine = ($writeLine, $property.Value -join '|')
            }

        } else {
            $writeLine = ($_.("Name"), $_.("Code") -join '|')
        }
    }
    $writer.WriteLine($writeLine)
}

$writer.Close()
```

Comment: `Import-Csv` and `Export-CSV` have the `-Delimiter` parameter which you could use the pipe character rather than `-join`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the Select-Object cmdlet. Example functionality

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\2Users50columns.csv' `
| Select-Object -Property 'Name','Classification','Age'

Name           : Esuriency  
Classification : Member
Age            : 35 minutes ago

Name           : Shawn
Classification : Member
Age            : 27
```

So you would insert a Select-Object:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'text.csv' | Select-Object ... | Foreach-Object {
```